# Improve Venn Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I wanted to draw this (attached) diagram but got stuck in the middle.
I want to make all words clear and white.

My Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
            
\definecolor{pgreen}{HTML}{95bda3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={text=white,draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}
  \node [venn circle = pgreen] (A) at (0,0) {Social};
  \node [venn circle = pgreen] (B) at (60:4cm) {\textbf{Environmental}};
  \node [venn circle = pgreen] (C) at (0:4cm) {Economic};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3.5,B=1/2 ) {Bearable}; 
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {Equitable};   
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/1.25,C=1/2 ) {Viable};   
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){Sustainable};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Producing this result:
[image]

Here are the icons

[image]
[image]
[image]

Orginal Diagram

[image]

Comment: Add `text = white` to the `tikzpicture` environment's options (or the nodes directly).

Comment: It is already there. \tikzset{venn circle/.style={text=white....

Comment: Looks like you need to recheck the RGB-value(s) of your color(s) ...

Comment: @OOzyPal But the four last nodes don't use it. The `venn circle` nodes do indeed have white text but I didn't even realize they were there since they are hardly visible.

Comment: @OOzyPal, looks like you also should use a bold font to avoid thin lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another approach, using `calc` library to place all. You probably want to change `opacity` for `fill opactity` too. And, of course, change the ducks for your icons.

**Remark:** The text looks *more white* in the pdf document, so I changed your green.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{venn circle/.style={thick,fill=green!30!black,fill opacity=1/3}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[text=white]
  \foreach[count=\j]\i in {Environtmental,Social,Economic}
  {
    \coordinate (\j) at (120*\j-30:2.5);
    \draw[venn circle] (\j) circle (3.5) node{\i};
    \node at (\j) {\i};
  }
  \node at ($(1)!0.5!(2)+(150:0.5)$) {Bearable};
  \node at ($(2)!0.5!(3)+(270:0.5)$) {Equitable};
  \node at ($(3)!0.5!(1)+ (30:0.5)$) {Viable};
  \node at (0,0) {Sustainable};
  % change the ducks for the icons
  \duck[shift={(-1,3.5)},water];
  \duck[shift={(-4,-4)},graduate];
  \duck[shift={(2,-4)},tshirt,jacket=black,tie];
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]